# Does $\int \frac{exp( -b\sqrt{a+x})}{\sqrt{x}} dx$ have a solution?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Is there a solution for the following integral:

$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\exp( -b\sqrt{a+x})}{\sqrt{x}} dx 
$$

where $a$ and $b$ are constants. If it is not, what is the best approximation?
Especially in the limit as $b \to \infty$.

In case of $a=0$, there is [an analytic solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513977/does-int-fracexp-bax3-2-sqrtx-dx-have-a-solution).

Comment: not for the general case...

Comment: So in which case?

Comment: what is the domain of integration? For big b the integral we be dominated by the region closest to zero

Comment: It is from 0 to $\infty$

Comment: If $b>>1$ and $a>0$ a the leading order asymptotics is given by
$$e^{-b\sqrt{a}}\frac{\sqrt {\pi\sqrt{a}}}{2\sqrt{b}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Letting $x=a\sinh^2t$, we have $I=2\sqrt a~K_1\Big(b\sqrt a\Big):$ see [Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) for more [information](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196401).